# NASM: emit MSW of non-scalar (link-time) value

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, ld, osdev

I am attempting to define a constant [IDT (Interrupt Descriptor Table)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_descriptor_table) entry in [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/), and to do so, I need to emit into a data table the high word of a double-word address *that is not resolved until link time*.  Is there a way to do it?

Here's the interrupt handler:

```
;;; Interrupt 3 (breakpoint) handler.  For now, just poke the screen and halt.

        align   8
int3:
        mov     [0xb8000],dword '* * '
        hlt
```

And here's the IDT entry that references it.  The most-significant and least-significant words of the offset need to be stored separately and non-contiguously:

```
        ;; Interrupt 3 - breakpoint
        dw      int3                    ; offset (low)    <---- WORKS
        dw      codesel                 ; code selector
        db      0                       ; unused
        db      0b10001111              ; present, ring 0, 32-bit trap gate
        dw      int3 >> 16              ; offset (high)   <---- ASSEMBLY ERROR
```

NASM correctly causes LD to emit the low word of int3's address, but the high word fails at assembly time with this error:

> pgm.asm:240: error: shift operator may only be applied to scalar values

NASM won't do math with a value that isn't defined until link time.  I understand, but I need a way to work around this.  I could:

- locate int3 absolutely
- Build the IDT at runtime instead of assembly time

I'll probably end up building the IDT at runtime, but it'd be good to know if there is a way to cause the assembler/linker to emit into a data table the high word of an address that is not resolved until link time.

---

Particulars:

- NASM 2.20.01<sup>1</sup>
- NASM output format `aout`
- LD version 2.22
- 32-bit mode (NASM "bits 32" directive issued)

<sup>1</sup> This is probably a typo; the latest version in my distro today is 2.12.01.  The latest version of nasm available at the time I wrote this question was 2.10.01.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861843/statically-defined-idt?rq=1 .  Strictly speaking, this question is a duplicate of that one -- it's the same problem, with the same cause (ld + swizzled IDT) but different languages.

Comment: The NASM version was probably 2.10.01 or such, there is no 2.20 series yet. The version 2.10.01 was released on at 2012-05-25 01:00 +0400, https://repo.or.cz/nasm.git/commitdiff/3d1d159e1c876308712fd5e21089dfddfbad1e69

Comment: @ecm It must have been a typo.  I'll add a note, thanks.

Comment: Related: a C version of the same problem: [How to do computations with addresses at compile/linking time?](//stackoverflow.com/q/31360888).  ELF doesn't have a relocation for this so you're basically screwed; you could have the OS do fixups after loading itself.

Comment: I know this question is over 6 years old, but I recently wrote an answer to a related question that offers up a solution by building IDT and GDTs in a linker script (and the C pre-processor): https://stackoverflow.com/a/58192043/3857942. This method has them built at link time.

Comment: Yes it would apply here, my answer there shows a NASM specific example as well so it is far more closely matched to this question. That answer though can be used for code generated by C/C++/rust etc since the work is being done by the linker script. If you provided a full piece of code in your question (making it an [mcve]. Even if it involves NASM and GCC or other language, one could create a specific answer to solve your problem,, but I feel like the other question/answer may be a very close duplicate of this. I realize after 6 years you may no longer have an example on hand.

Comment: @MichaelPetch There's something particularly satisfying in voting to close your own question in favor of a superior one.  Thanks!

Comment: It isn't superior IMHO. What I did though is rather than ask about the problem, asked for actual solutions. I was hoping that initial question/answer might entice others to provide their own mechanisms and create new answers. It just so happened yours became a duplicate. It is good though that we can clean up the OSDev tag a bit at the same time.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I know you did, and thank you.  I wasn't being sarcastic--I think your q/a is very good, and I'm glad for mine to be a dup of it.

Comment: Didn't think there was sarcasm at all!

Answer (score 3):

Well... as you probably know, Nasm will condescend to do a shift on the difference between two labels. The usual construct is something like:

`dw (int3 - $$) >> 16`

where `$$` refers to the beginning of the section. This calculates the "file offset". This is probably not the value you want to shift.

`dw (int3 - $$ + ORIGIN) >> 16`

may do what you want... where `ORIGIN` is... well, what we told Nasm for `org`, if we were using flat binary. I ASSume you're assembling to `-f elf32` or `-f elf64`, telling ld `--oformat=binary`, and telling ld either in a linker script or on the command line where you want `.text` to be (?). This seems to work.
I made an interesting discovery: if you tell ld `-oformat=binary` (one hyphen) instead of `--oformat=binary` (two hyphens), ld silently outputs nothing! Don't do this - you waste a lot of time!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm assembling to "-f aout", but "-f elf32" doesn't change anything: either way, ORG is rejected by nasm since I'm not generating a flat binary.  I guess that points to the "absolutely locate (part of) my program" workaround, if I don't want to build the IDT at runtime.  Re "Don't do this": :)

Comment: `ld` has a lot of one-letter options, including `-o output_filename`.  So `ld -o 'format=binary'` is how it parses with only one dash.