# NASM: Define static IDT at compile time without using the linker

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, osdev

I am trying to make a static IDT in 32-bit mode with only assembly.

I can make the lower half of the address without errors by using `dw isr`, but when I use `dw isr >> 16` to define the higher half of the address, NASM gives me the following error:

> idt.asm:25: error: shift operator may only be applied to scalar values

Is there any way to make the IDT using NASM ?

PS. Yes, I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58192042/solution-needed-for-building-a-static-idt-and-gdt-at-assemble-compile-link-time), but I don't want to use the linker since my kernel is very small and all written in assembly.

Comment: Do label arithmetic to gain a scalar value that NASM will allow to shift. For example, if your section starts with (say) `org 7C00h` then you can do arithmetic like `dw (isr - $$ + 7C00h) >> 16`. In general, the delta between two labels that are in the same section results in a scalar value that you can then use in all kinds of calculations, including shifts and division.

Comment: If you edit your question to include more of a complete example I may be able to tell you the exact calculation that you need.